# use operator chaining on pandas data frame to read data, del unwanted columns, rename columns and read few rows

Tags: excel, python-2.7, pandas, select, multiple-columns

I have a data set to read and do some cleaning of the data before final use.

I know how to do that by following separate independent steps as follows:

```
    data = pd.read_excel('C:\Users\pappu.a.kumar\Documents\data\coursera\python\Energy Indicators.xls',skiprows=17, skip_footer=0)
    del data['Unnamed: 0']
    del data['Unnamed: 1']
    data.columns = ['Country', 'Energy Supply', 'Energy Supply per Capita', '% Renewable']
    fdata = data.ix[:226]
```

Now i want to do all these steps using operator chaining. My first attempt to do so is written below:

```
    data = (pd.read_excel('C:\Users\pappu.a.kumar\Documents\data\coursera\python\Energy Indicators.xls',skiprows=17, skip_footer=0)
      .(del data['Unnamed: 0'])
      .(del data['Unnamed: 1'])
      .(columns = ['Country', 'Energy Supply', 'Energy Supply per Capita', '% Renewable'])
      .(ix[:226]))
```

But this code is producing the following error:

> File "", line 3
>
> .(del data['Unnamed: 0'])
>
> ^
>
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

I don't know what i am doing is logically possible or not. If it is possible, any reference to right document or in the code itself will be much appreciated.

Comment: You're looking for `.drop('Unnamed: 0', axis=1)`.

Comment: Thanks, It did help. @IanS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If position of unnamed columns is still same, use parameter `names` in [`read_excel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html) for set new colum names and then delete unnecessary columns by [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html). For selecting is possible use `.iloc[226]`, `.head(226)`, `.ix(226)`:

```
#2 last columns are unnecessary - 2 last values of list in parameter names are 'tmp1' and 'tmp2'
data = pd.read_excel('C:\Users\pappu.a.kumar\Documents\data\coursera\python\Energy Indicators.xls',skiprows=17, skip_footer=0, names=['Country', 'Energy Supply', 'Energy Supply per Capita', '% Renewable', 'tmp1', 'tmp2'])
         .drop(['tmp1','tmp2'], axis=1)
         .head(226)
```

Another possible solution is rename columns:

```
data = pd.read_excel('C:\Users\pappu.a.kumar\Documents\data\coursera\python\Energy Indicators.xls',skiprows=17, skip_footer=0)
         .drop(['Unnamed: 0','Unnamed: 1'], axis=1)
         .rename(columns={'firstcol':'Country', 'secondcol': 'Energy Supply', ...})
         .head(226)
```

Comment: @piRSquared. Congrats. Perhaps you could frame the other guy for something so he gets banned? Just kidding.

Comment: Will this work the same if dropped columns aren't the last ones?